# TypeScript Compile Error with Strict Setting on react-select Event Handler

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am writing a React component in TypeScript with `strict: true` in `tsconfig.json`.

Given the following in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "ajv": "^6.5.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "less": "^3.8.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "reactstrap": "^6.3.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.4",
    "webpack-command": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0-14",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.1.0-11",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.8",
    "@types/react-select": "^2.0.4",
    "@types/reactstrap": "^6.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.9",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "react-compound-slider": "^0.15.0",
    "react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2"
  }
```

I have found an error with an event handler for `react-select` that only appears in `strict` mode.

Here is the `react-select` component:

```
<Select options={options}
        isMulti={true}
        onChange={this.props.handler(this.props.name)} />
```

The handler function in the props is curried and has this shape:

```
handler: (s: string) => (o: Array<Option>) => void
```

where `Option` is a pedestrian container.

```
export interface Option {
    value: string
    label: string
}
```

The compilation error is this:

```
TS2322: Type '(o: Option[]) => void' is not assignable to type '(value:
              ValueType<Option>, action: ActionMeta) => void'.
```

As I mentioned before, there were no issues before I went `strict`.

Can you explain what the issue is here and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the error message, the first parameter that `react-select` is passing to your handler is of type `ValueType<Option>`; if you look at the definitions of `ValueType` and `OptionsType`, you'll see that expands to `Option | Option[] | null | undefined`.  When you enable `strictFunctionTypes` (which is part of `strict`), your handler function is required to accept the type passed by `react-select` or a supertype (more general type).  In particular, your handler function must accept `Option` as well as `Option[]`.  If you additionally enable `strictNullChecks` (which is also part of `strict`), then your handler function must also deal with `null` and `undefined`.

Without `strictFunctionTypes`, the handler is allowed to accept a subtype of `ValueType<Option>`, even though this is unsound because `react-select` could pass the handler an argument that it can't handle.  See [this handbook page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) for more information.

Comment: [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4468617/matt-mccutchen) when you say "look at the definitions" you mean [this file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-select/lib/types.d.ts)?
Does it mean in this strict mode we always have to specify those four types, isn't there any other way?